# node.js write filestream disordered in p2p file download

Tags: javascript, node.js, download, filestream, p2p

guys. I try to use node.js to create a p2p file sharing application. While downloading a file, it will download the file block by block.

The block size used in the following code is 1KB. But it has a problem, when available sockets number MAX_SOCKET_CNT is set to 30, it will not work.

**How to run the code:**

First, run `node server.js`, then,  run `node client.js`, this will download the file named `fav.mp3` to `fav-local.mp3`.

After downloading, try to run `diff fav.mp3 fav-local.mp3` to check if the file downloaded completely.

Could you help me to figure out where the problem is?

Any answer or suggestion is welcome. Thanks in advance.

### Here is the source code:

### server.js

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
var fs = require('fs');

function downloadBlock(request, response){
  var urlParts = url.parse(request.url, true);
  var query = urlParts.query;

  if('block_id' in query){
      response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "audio/mpeg"});
      var startHere=parseInt(query["block_id"]);
      var BLOCK_SIZE=1024;
      var currentPosition=startHere*BLOCK_SIZE;
      var readStream = fs.createReadStream('fav.mp3',{start: startHere*BLOCK_SIZE, end:startHere*BLOCK_SIZE+BLOCK_SIZE-1});
      readStream.pipe(response);
  }else{
      response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
      response.write("refused");
      response.end();
      console.log("Warning: not a file block download request...");
  }
}


http.createServer(downloadBlock).listen(8801);
console.log("Server has started. please ensure that the fav.mp3 file(size=439355B) is here.");
```

---

### client.js

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var remoteFile='fav.mp3';
var fileSize=439355;
var localFile='fav-local.mp3';
var totalBlocks=Math.floor((fileSize+1023)/1024);
/**************************************************/
//KEY POINT
var MAX_SOCKET_CNT=totalBlocks; //worked
//var MAX_SOCKET_CNT=30;//not work //????because of  recursive  downloadBlock function????
/*************************************************/
for(var i=0;i<MAX_SOCKET_CNT;++i){
        downloadBlock('127.0.0.1',8801,remoteFile, localFile,i,totalBlocks);
}

function downloadBlock(IP,PORT,remoteFile,localFile,blockID,totalBlocksNum){
        if(blockID >= totalBlocksNum) return;
        var BLOCK_SIZE=1024;
        var file = fs.createWriteStream(localFile,{start: blockID*BLOCK_SIZE});
        var request = http.get("http://localhost:"+PORT+"/download_block?block_id="+blockID, function(response) {
          response.pipe(file);
          file.on('finish', function() {
                var callback=function downloadBlockOver(){
                        console.log("compelete download blockID:"+blockID);
                        var nextBlockID=blockID+MAX_SOCKET_CNT;
                        if(nextBlockID<totalBlocksNum){
                                downloadBlock(IP,PORT,remoteFile,localFile,nextBlockID,totalBlocksNum); //why not this work if MAX_SOCKET_CNT=30???    
                        }
                }
                file.close(callback);
           });
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aha. 
Finally, I find out the solution. You have to create the file first. Then change the flag of write stream with "r+" before download.

```
function touchFile(fileName,fileSize){
    var BLOCK_SIZE=1024;
    var totalBlocks=Math.floor((fileSize+BLOCK_SIZE-1)/BLOCK_SIZE);
    var file = fs.createWriteStream(fileName);
    var blockBuffer=new Buffer(BLOCK_SIZE);
    for(var i=0;i<totalBlocks-1;++i){
            file.write(blockBuffer,0, BLOCK_SIZE);
    }
    var leftToFill=new Buffer(fileSize-(totalBlocks-1)*BLOCK_SIZE);
    file.write(leftToFill,0, leftToFill.Length);
    file.end();
}
```

add the function "touchFile(localFile,fileSize);" before downloadBlock. 
Then change:

```
var file = fs.createWriteStream(localFile,{start: blockID*BLOCK_SIZE});
```

to

```
var file = fs.createWriteStream(localFile,{start: blockID*BLOCK_SIZE,flags:'r+',autoClose: true});
```

It will work now.

Answer (score 0):

touchFile just work when MAX_SOCKET_CNT==3. 
**The final solution is use node module random-access-file**:https://github.com/mafintosh/random-access-file

### The client.js code:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var randomAccessFile = require('random-access-file');


var remoteFile='fav.mp3';
var fileSize=439355;
//var fileSize=6000;//363213; //439355;
var localFile='fav-local.mp3';
var totalBlocks=Math.floor((fileSize+1023)/1024);
/**************************************************/
//KEY POINT
//var MAX_SOCKET_CNT=totalBlocks; //worked
var MAX_SOCKET_CNT=20;//worked
/*************************************************/

var file = randomAccessFile('fav-local.mp3');
for(var i=0;i<MAX_SOCKET_CNT;++i){
    downloadBlock('127.0.0.1',8801,remoteFile, localFile,i,totalBlocks);
}
file.close();

function downloadBlock(IP,PORT,remoteFile,localFile,blockID,totalBlocksNum){
    if(blockID >= totalBlocksNum) return;
    var BLOCK_SIZE=1024;
    var chunks=[];
    var request = http.get("http://localhost:"+PORT+"/download_block?block_id="+blockID, function(response) {
      response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
      });
      response.on('error', function (e) { 
        console.log('error.......'+e);
      });
      response.on('close', function () { 
        console.log('close ....');
      });
      response.on('end', function () { 
        var dataToProcess=Buffer.concat(chunks);
        console.log('block data size: ' + dataToProcess.length);
        file.write(blockID*BLOCK_SIZE, dataToProcess,
                    function(err) {
                            if(err){
                                    console.log("error in write...");
                            }else{
                                var nextBlockID=blockID+MAX_SOCKET_CNT;
                                if(nextBlockID<totalBlocksNum){
                                        console.log("download next block:"+nextBlockID);
                                        downloadBlock(IP,PORT,remoteFile,localFile,nextBlockID,totalBlocksNum);   
                                }    
                }
                    }
              );
      });
    });
}
```